# Merging sheets on Excel with data going to particular columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two different sheets (forest_cover and public_health) that have the same data structure: geocode (Y axis) x year (X axis).

Exemple of public_health:

```
Geocode |   2000  |   2001   |   2002   |    2003   | 
2010564 |--246-   | --113-   |--485-    |--394-     |
```

Exemple of forest_cover:

```
Geocode |   2000  |   2001   |   2002   |    2003   | 
2010564 |--402-   | --411-   |--387-    |--449-     |
```

Even though the sheets are structured in the same way, the data in the cells cannot be added together because they are different values; respectively the forest cover of a given municipality in kilometers and the number of people infected with a specific disease.

I want to - and this is where it gets tricky:

1. filter the public_health sheet using the geocodes contained on "forest_cover" (so that it only displays geocodes contained in both sheets) and
2. merge the two sheets, having the data placed in a specific pattern, as I will try to demonstrate below (since I'm a new user, I cannot post pictures):

   ```
   Geocode|-----------2000-------------|------------2001-----------|-------------2002----------|
          |For_cov_v|infected          |For_cov_v|infected         |For_cov_v|infected|
   ```

For_cov_v = forest cover value (refer to ex. 2)

infected = no. of infected people (refer to ex. 1)

Please note that the year cell is a merged cell that contains 2 columns with the data of forest coverage and no. of infected people.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Use IFERROR combined with a lookup function (e.g. VLOOKUP) to merge the two datasets together.  Add an additional column that notes whether you have data for both values.
2. Use a pivot table to lay out the data with years as columns and the two variables as the "data values."  Use the filter option on the pivot table to filter out any cases where you don't have both variables.